# Multiple lines in ternary operator clause with EJS

Tags: javascript, ejs, ternary-operator

I'm trying to use a multiple line ternary clause to conditionally render different content on the page depending on whether or not the currentUser is the owner of the post.

If they made the post, I want to show the edit/delete buttons. If they aren't the owner, I want to display username of the owner of the post.

I've had similar issues with this with React, until I realized that I just needed to throw in a whole bunch of parens() to make it work.

Here is my current EJS code (formatted more or less the way I would have written it if I were using JSX):

```
<% (currentUser && artpiece.author.id.equals(currentUser._id)) ? ( %>

   <a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' href='/artpieces/<%= artpiece._id %>/edit'>Edit</a>
   <form style='display: inline' action="/artpieces/<%= artpiece._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
        <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this artpiece?')">Delete</button>
<% </form> ) : ( %>

<% <p><em>Submitted by <%= artpiece.author.username %></em></p> ) %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same if you use a normal if else conditional? i use ternary operator when i want to write everything in one line

Comment: @SunriseM Yes, that is the solution I ended up going with. But I was still interested to know why the ternary operator wasn't working. I suppose you're right though: maybe I should just use ternaries when I want to write a succinct one liner. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use ternary operators like that with EJS.

While JSX compiles directly into plain old JavaScript, EJS compiles into an intermediary string representation with a lot more cruft [including added semicolons](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/master/lib/ejs.js#L746). In practice, this means you can only start EJS tags where JavaScript would accept a semicolon prefix<sup>†</sup>, and unfortunately, ternary operators break with the way EJS adds the semicolons. You can see the generated output if you enable debugging at compiled time:

```
// EJS for an if else statement
ejs.compile(
  `<% if (true) { %>yes<% } else { %>no <% } %>`,
  { debug: true }
)

// Generated JS for evaluation
// Notice that each <% %> turns into a '    ; ' + line + '\n';
var __output = [], __append = __output.push.bind(__output);
with (locals || {}) {
  ;  if (true) { 
  ; __append("yes")
  ;  } else { 
  ; __append("no ")
  ;  } 
}

// EJS for a ternary statement
ejs.compile(
   `<% true ? ( %>yes<% ) : ( %>no <% ) %>`,
   { debug: true }
)

// Generated JS, again each <% %> turns into '    ; ' + line + '\n';
// but this time, the JavaScript generated is invalid.

var __output = [], __append = __output.push.bind(__output);
with (locals || {}) {
  ;  true ? ( 
  ; __append("yes")
  ;  ) : ( 
  ; __append("no ")
  ;  ) 
}
return __output.join("");
```

† JavaScript accepts semicolons in more places than one would expect. For example, you can place a semicolon after any brace that opens a block, since that semicolon would delimit an empty statement.

```
; if (true) {; console.log("it's true!"); };
; while (true) {; console.log("it's true!"); break; };
; function whaaat(a) {; console.log(`it's ${a}!`); };
```

Comment: Wow! @faraz thank you for such a complete explanation of why that doesn't work. Makes perfect sense. And I learned a new word: cruft. Thanks again!